# how to write JOIN query in node.js sequalize?

Tags: node.js, join, sequelize.js

I am executing `join` query in `node.js` using `sequelize` . How to write join queries using sequelize ? thank you in advance. have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define associations between your models. If I have two models `User` and `Customers`, I can define and association like this

```
User.belongsTo(Customer);
Customer.hasMany(User);
```

Then when you query you can join by specifying `include` in the options

```
Customer.finOne({
  where: {
    id: 1,
  },
  include: {
    model: User,
    where: {
      id: 4,
    }
  }
}
```